# Summarizing data using an MVC application

Tags: javascript, c#, mysql

I am looking for either an existing framework or software that would allow us to summarize our large MySQL database and allow us to present the information in the form of charts or tables.

I have looked online and found a few that are standalone web services, however for our purposes we would need it to be embedded without our existing web app and able to run either on the front end or on our server.

we would also be able to make use of any existing framework(c#) for data aggregation as we could implement them in c# on our server and display the information using JavaScript. We are trying to avoid implementing our own version due to time constraints so any pre-made method would be preferable.

I know this is a fairly vague question but we are just looking for some suggestions as the topic of web based data analysis doesn't seem to return many useful options for us.

Comment: I would say that something of this nature likely requires bespoke coding for the mining, and a 3rd party library for chart generation. Since your data is likely very unique a generic solution is never going to give you the best picture.

Comment: I did expect that this may be the case. thanks for your help. could you recommend any frameworks or examples that may help with implementing this using c#.

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic on StackOverflow.